OpenCV | While fisheye undistortion how to account camera orientaion?
Hello
I am trying to get the DOWN-looking view from a fisheye-distorted image.
The current camera orientation is depicted below. If seen from the left view, camera is looking down, 40deg from the forward axis towards the down axis. If seen from the top view the camera is tilted toward left by 30deg from the forward axis.

I have made a python3 script, but not satisfied with the output. I think there is something wrong with how I account for the camera orientation.
import cv2
import numpy as np

rollDeg = 50
pitchDeg = 30
# Camera calibration parameters
K = np.array([[413.4459003089536, 0.0, 625.4657090067509],
          [0.0, 414.5602416017697, 393.99252903112915],
          [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

D = np.array([[0.2422953376828772],
          [0.5059306403608751],
          [-0.48731143899233426],
          [0.17754105229960523]])

# Estimate a new camera matrix optimized for undistortion
new_K = cv2.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(K, D, (1280, 720), np.eye(3), balance=1, new_size=(1280, 720), fov_scale=1)

# Initial values for new_K parameters
fx_init = 230
fy_init = 230
cx_init = 1280//2
cy_init = 720//2

# Function to update undistorted image
def update_image():
# Update new_K matrix based on trackbar values
rollDeg    = cv2.getTrackbarPos('roll', 'img')
pitchDeg      = cv2.getTrackbarPos('pitch', 'img')
new_K[0, 0] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('fx', 'img')
new_K[1, 1] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('fy', 'img')
new_K[0, 2] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('cx', 'img')
new_K[1, 2] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('cy', 'img')

roll = rollDeg * np.pi / 180
pitch = -pitchDeg * np.pi / 180

# ******** I am doubtful about these couple of lines **********  
# Rotation matrices for roll (rotX) and pitch (rotY)
rotX = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                 [0, np.cos(roll), -np.sin(roll)],
                 [0, np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll)]])

rotY = np.array([[np.cos(pitch), 0, np.sin(pitch)],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [-np.sin(pitch), 0, np.cos(pitch)]])

# Combined rotation matrix
rotation = rotX @ rotY

# Calculate rotated intrinsic matrix
K_rotated = rotation @ K

# Generate undistortion map
mapx, mapy = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K_rotated, D, rotation, new_K, (1280, 720), cv2.CV_16SC2)
# ********         **********  

# Remap input image using undistortion map
undistorted_image = cv2.remap(input_image, mapx, mapy, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

# Display undistorted image
cv2.imshow('img', undistorted_image)
#cv2.imwrite('undistortedImg.jpg', undistorted_image)

# Load input image
input_image = cv2.imread("distortedImg.png")

# Create named window and trackbars
cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.createTrackbar('roll', 'img', int(rollDeg), 89, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('pitch', 'img', int(pitchDeg), 89, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('fx', 'img', fx_init, 500, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('fy', 'img', fy_init, 500, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('cx', 'img', cx_init, 1920, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('cy', 'img', cy_init, 1080, lambda x: update_image())

# Initialize undistorted image
update_image()

# Wait for key press to exit
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

distortedImg.png

undistortedImg.png


import cv2
import numpy as np

rollDeg = 50
pitchDeg = 30
# Camera calibration parameters
K = np.array([[413.4459003089536, 0.0, 625.4657090067509],
              [0.0, 414.5602416017697, 393.99252903112915],
              [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

D = np.array([[0.2422953376828772],
              [0.5059306403608751],
              [-0.48731143899233426],
              [0.17754105229960523]])

# Estimate a new camera matrix optimized for undistortion
new_K = cv2.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(K, D, (1280, 720), np.eye(3), balance=1, new_size=(1280, 720), fov_scale=1)

# Initial values for new_K parameters
fx_init = 82
fy_init = 82
cx_init = 1000
cy_init = 600

# Function to update undistorted image
def update_image():
    # Update new_K matrix based on trackbar values
    rollDeg    = cv2.getTrackbarPos('roll', 'img')
    pitchDeg      = cv2.getTrackbarPos('pitch', 'img')
    new_K[0, 0] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('fx', 'img')
    new_K[1, 1] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('fy', 'img')
    new_K[0, 2] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('cx', 'img')
    new_K[1, 2] = cv2.getTrackbarPos('cy', 'img')

    roll = rollDeg * np.pi / 180
    pitch = -pitchDeg * np.pi / 180

    # Rotation matrices for roll (rotX) and pitch (rotY)
    rotX = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                     [0, np.cos(roll), -np.sin(roll)],
                     [0, np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll)]])

    # rotY = np.array([[np.cos(pitch), 0, np.sin(pitch)],
    #                  [0, 1, 0],
    #                  [-np.sin(pitch), 0, np.cos(pitch)]])

    rotZ = np.array([[np.cos(pitch), -np.sin(pitch), 0],
                     [np.sin(pitch),  np.cos(pitch), 0],
                     [0, 0, 1]])

    # Combined rotation matrix
    rotation = rotZ @ rotX

    # Calculate rotated intrinsic matrix
    # K_rotated = rotation @ K

    # Generate undistortion map
    mapx, mapy = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, rotation, new_K, (1280, 720), cv2.CV_16SC2)

    # Remap input image using undistortion map
    undistorted_image = cv2.remap(input_image, mapx, mapy, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    # Display undistorted image
    cv2.imshow('img', undistorted_image)
    # cv2.imshow('img', cv2.rotate(undistorted_image, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE))

# Load input image
input_image = cv2.imread("distortedImg.png")

# Create named window and trackbars
cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.createTrackbar('roll', 'img', int(rollDeg), 89, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('pitch', 'img', int(pitchDeg), 89, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('fx', 'img', fx_init, 500, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('fy', 'img', fy_init, 500, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('cx', 'img', cx_init, 1920, lambda x: update_image())
cv2.createTrackbar('cy', 'img', cy_init, 1080, lambda x: update_image())

# Initialize undistorted image
update_image()

# Wait for key press to exit
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

